# PayPal Express Checkout CHECKOUTSTATUS always be PaymentActionNotInitiated in sandbox

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

As the title mentioned, In sandbox, no matter what action I did,  `CHECKOUTSTATUS` in the query response through `GetExpressCheckoutDetails`-Method always be `PaymentActionNotInitiated`.

Is there anything wrong with sandbox, or what configurations should be modified?

Answer (score 0):

The Status would be `Paymentactionnotinitiated` whenever you did not redirect to the return URL (https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX ) and failed to login to paypal account or enter credit card details after the `setexpresscheckout" API request, which is necessary.

Comment: but I have already done the processed as you said, firstly, I redirected to paypal sandbox and  I login with a personal sanbox account ,confirm the order,at this time ,CHECKOUTSTATUS  is  PaymentActionNotInitiated, secondly,even I called the doExpressCheckoutPayment, the  CHECKOUTSTATUS  is PaymentActionNotInitiated

Comment: is your merchant account verified/confirmed?

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't call the "DoExpressCheckoutPayment" method.

$this->PPHttpPost('DoExpressCheckoutPayment', $padata);